# With Date=as.Date(rownames(df))

Tags: r, excel, date, nls

I called index data from an excel csv. (Dates are in yyyy/mm/dd format.)

```
 library(tseries)
 library(minpack.lm)
 library(ggplot2)
 index <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\deks\\DATA.csv")
 ts <- index
 df <- data.frame(ts)
 df <- data.frame(ts)
 df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(rownames(df)),Y=df$Close)
```

I received the error:

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

and for

```
  df$days<-as.numeric(df$Date-df[1,]$Date)
```

I received

> Warning message: In Ops.factor(df$Date, df[1, ]$Date) : - not
>   meaningful for factors

I set the data as `X=DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)` and `Y=INDEX VALUE`.

I changed the date to [(DD/MM/YYYY),(DD-MM-YYYY),(YYYY-MM-DD)] and still the error appears. 
How can I proceed?

Comment: When in r, run this command: `df$Date[1]` and show us the output.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName output is [1] 1991/08/19
595 Levels: 1991/08/19 1991/08/20 1991/08/21 1991/08/22 ... 1994/01/06

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Step 2:

```
index <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\deks\\DATA.csv")
ts <- index
df <- data.frame(ts)
df <- data.frame(ts)
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(rownames(df), "%Y/%m/%d"),Y=df$Close)
```

Comment: Also, you should look around for some R resources/tutorials.  This is your first programming language I assume?

Comment: tq for ur help. Now i can proceed to next line..but output of Date show NA-not available....how?...